# Time portion of datetime truncated when as.POSIXlt applied to many rows

Tags: r, datetime

Trying to translate a datetime string into something a bit more structured, so that I have access to values like month, hour, etc...

Getting some strange behavior. Namely, when I apply as.POSIXlt to a "small" number of values, I get the expected output:

```
NUM_ROWS = 10
df$dt[1:NUM_ROWS] = as.POSIXlt(df$datetime[1:NUM_ROWS])
df$dt[1]
// "2008-04-08 15:00:00 CDT"
```

However, if I try to apply as.POSIXlt over the entire length of the dataframe, only the date (not the hours) are kept:

```
NUM_ROWS = 58310
df$dt[1:NUM_ROWS] = as.POSIXlt(df$datetime[1:NUM_ROWS])
df$dt[1]
// "2008-04-08 CDT"
```

Why can't I apply this function (as.POSIXlt) over the entire data frame and retain the HH:MM:SS?

**UPDATE**

As per Soheil's suggestion, this command works:

```
df$dt[1:NUM_ROWS] = as.POSIXlt(df$datetime[1:NUM_ROWS], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: Define the format, see if that is the problem.

Comment: @Soheil do you mean as a second argument to POSIXlt?

Comment: Yes, format and tz sometimes solve problems.

Comment: @Soheil works, if you want to add it as answer i'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the format.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so I will 'answer'.

First check class of your `datetime` variable:
`class(df$datetime)`

If it is character check for values of it- make sure, that everywhere there are hours, minutes and seconds:
`table(nchar(df$datetime))`

Probably there is a row with only day like '2015-09-16'.
If that is the case you can add hours and minutes manually:

`df$datetime[nchar(df$datetime)==10] <- paste0(df$datetime[nchar(df$datetime)==10], rep(' 00:00:00', sum(nchar(df$datetime)==10)))`

Comment: class(df$datetime) == "factor"

Comment: How about `table(nchar(as.character(df$datetime)))`